# Angular2: runtime error when binding a <select> combo box to a list of objects retrieved from an API in ngOnInit()

Tags: html, angular

I am busy with a angular2 web app, I have a select html combo box which i'm trying to bind to an array  of Active Stock take objects.  My app seems to compile without any issues but I get the following runtime error.  Any idea what this means?  Am I going about this the wrong way?  is it possible to do this with safe navigation using ?

My error:

```
zone.js:420
Unhandled Promise rejection:Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined; Zone:<root>; Task:Promise.then; Value:TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
    at SyntaxError.set [as stack] (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:75980:61)
    at assignAll (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111629:29)
    at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111700:16)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:75942:16)
    at new SyntaxError (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6861:16)
    at TemplateParser.parse (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:21436:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:55485:68)
    at 
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:55368:62

    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:55368:19)
    at createResult (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:55251:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111167:26)
    at Zone.run (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111038:43)
    at 
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111460:57

    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111200:35)
TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
    at SyntaxError.set [as stack] (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:75980:61)
    at assignAll (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111629:29)
    at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111700:16)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:75942:16)
    at new SyntaxError (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6861:16)
    at TemplateParser.parse (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:21436:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:55485:68)
    at 
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:55368:62

    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:55368:19)
    at createResult (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:55251:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111167:26)
    at Zone.run (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111038:43)
    at 
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111460:57

    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111200:35)
zone.js:422
list of 1 items
aaZoneAwareError{stack: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot se…calhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111358:35) [<root>]", message: "Uncaught (in
promise): TypeError: Cannot set prope…http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111200:35)", originalStack: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
se…http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111358:35)", zoneAwareStack: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot se…calhost:4200/vendor.bundl
```

My html:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="activeStockTakes?">
    <option *ngFor="let activeStockTake of activeStockTakes" [ngValue]="activeStockTake">{{activeStockTake.UserCode}} - {{activeStockTake.Comment}}
    </option>
</select>
```

My ngOninit of my stock-takeComponent.ts:

```
this.restService.getActiveStockTakes()
  .subscribe(
   res => {
    this.activeStockTakes = res;
    console.log(this.activeStockTakes);
   },
   res => {
    console.log(res);
   }
  );
}
```

Comment: Binding [(ngModel)] to an array seems really strange, you should bind it to a variable like `selectedStock`.
Also, you should initialize activeStockTages to an empty array in the constructor of your component.

Comment: @Melou I receive a list of open stock takes from the API in the constructor, So should I bind ngModel to e.g. selectedStockTake and then use the ngFor in the option tag with the array of stockTakes to populate the combo box?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a redundant `?` at the end of `[(ngModel)]="activeStockTakes?"`

The binding to `ngModel` can't be the array you use to generate the `<option>` elements

```
[(ngModel)]="activeStockTakes"
```

should be something like

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedActiveStockTakes"
```